# sprintf/printf right pad float with zeros in fixed width field

Tags: perl, printf

I am using PERL (for legacy reasons) and I would like to format fixed width columns in a CSV file. How do I format the following values:

1.0001
10.0001
100.0001
1000.0001
1000000.1
**100000001**

into fixed width of 8 by right padding floats with zeros or truncating, **BUT** if a large integer is encountered the field width must grow to accomodate:

1.000100
10.00010
100.0001
1000.000
1000000.
**100000001**

I am not performing any operations, so they could possibly be treated as strings or other. I've tried about every combination in the [sprintf](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html) documentation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[*The question was changed after this was posted. This no longer answers the question.*]

```
substr(sprintf("%.6f", $x), 0, 8)
```

or

```
substr($x.("0"x5), 0, 8)
```

Comment: And there's the neater way

Comment: That does it! Thanks to you both.

Comment: This solution presents an issue: it may truncate very large floats or integers. For example, 100000001 becomes 10000000 (incorrect) and 1000000.1 becomes 1000000. (not incorrect but unseemly). Any ideas?

Comment: @bejota, No, it's not a problem with the solution, it's a problem with the specs. My code provides the requested output. If you actually want different output, you'll need to specify what that output is.

Comment: Right on. I didn't specify in the question. Edit added.

Comment: I don't see any changes. The bottom half of your question says the top half is wrong, but you still haven't specified what you do want.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a neater way, but this example should work:

```
my @array = qw(1.0001 10.0001 100.0001 1000.0001);

for my $nums (@array) {  
    $nums .= '0' while length $nums < 8;
    print "$nums\n";
}
```

---

```
1.000100
10.00010
100.0001
1000.0001
```

Comment: Your `eval sprintf` line is equivalent to `my $adj = $nums`.  I also can't make sense of what `%8f` is supposed to do based off the documentation.  It appears to equate to `%.6f`, but I can't figure out why.